# Center point for all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange-2.0

After someone moved one of my questions here I discovered many Stack Exchange sites:

- Stack Overflow
- Meta Stack Overflow
- Photography

and others.

I can't find a really nice way to browse between them and I would like to have a central status place... Like all the answers I got in all the sites...

Is it possible?

edit: as Lance Roberts suggested it's not really clear but - I want to see the site that I'm registered to (a filter on the rest of the sites)

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/

Comment: it's nice, but clastrofobic :) ... I really think that having a welcome screen like in outlook that gives you an over view of all your emails, tasks etc... in the form of new answers/question/points and maybe more staff like points of interest can be really nice

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is http://stackexchange.com

You can go to your profiles (and hence lists of questions and answers) on other sites via the "accounts" tab of your current profile.

A central accounts page has been asked for before - I'll see if I can find the links.

Comment: it is good but it doesnot group my Q&A

Comment: @Asaf - more info in answer

Answer (score 1):

First, hit the `Stack Exchange` button at the top:

[image: StackExchangeButton]

Then, hit the `All Sites` button, and scroll through the sites and choose them:

[image: StackExchangeDropDown]

The `inbox` button will show the answers and comments directed to you.

Comment: it does not allow me to filter my sites  (Juan Manuel gave me an answer in the same spirit of yours... So...my remarks are there, thanks anyway )

Comment: @Asaf, ok, you might want to edit the filtering that you want into the question.

Answer (score -1):

Well, as far as comments and reputation goes, you can get some of that at [StackCenter](http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com):

[image]
<sub>(source: [quickmediasolutions.com](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/stackcenter.png))</sub>

*Disclaimer: I made it.*

Comment: While these broken links may provide some temporary hope, it is better to provide a substantial answer and send the broken links to the bit bucket. Answers that are little more than a collection of broken links may be removed.